# Cannot read property 'click' of undefined In magento 2 phtml file

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, console

Script in  filename.phtml

```
      <script>
       require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

                //   $('.swatch-option')[0].css('color','red');
                  $('.swatch-option').get(0).click();
                  alert('123');

        });
</script>
```

Error in Console

> filename.html:1028 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of
>   undefined

Comment: try with this - [0].click();

Comment: no way, already check

Comment: can you please check, may be (.'swatch-option').get(0) have multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dependency `'domReady!'`.

```
<script>
       require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'domReady!'], function($){
                  $('.swatch-option').get(0).click();
                  alert('123');

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined same error showing in console

Comment: you write in file static ?