# Custom Javascript is not working in my core HTML file. Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, pub

I'm trying to add some **Javascript** and **Jquery** in the **core theme** file which is located in 
`magento\pub\static\frontend\magento\luma\en_US\Magento_Checkout\template\payment+methods\list.html`

```
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<div class="myJazz">
    <label for="show_hide_jazz">
         <input type="radio" name="payment[methods]" id="show_hide_jazz">JazzCash
    </label>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("ASadssss")</script>
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()" class="items payment-methods">
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"class="payment-group">
        <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
             translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
             class="step-title"
             data-role="title">
        </div>
        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
   <script>
       window.alert("running");        
       require(['jquery', "jquery/ui" ], function($){
       'use strict';
       window.alert("running");
                $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_c").hide();
        $("#show_hide_jazz").on('change',function(){
            if($("#show_hide_jazz").attr('checked'))
            {
                $("#custom_jazz_s").show();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").show();
                $("#custom_jazz_c").show();
            }else{
                $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_c").hide();
            }
        });
        });        
    </script>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

In the code I separate my code by giving space... on the top two lines and at the end **Jquery** code is mine but it is not working.. even in the above I checked the simple Javascript is also not working... and second question can we code in **pub** folder??? if not then how can we make changes in pub files?

**My Extension code**

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/registration.php

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CheckoutJazz_Radio',
    __DIR__
);
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/etc/Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CheckoutJazz_Radio" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">CheckoutJazz_Radio/js/view/payment/list</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> CheckoutJazz/Redio/view/frontend/web/js/view/papyment/list.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';


    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/payment-methods/list',
            visible: paymentMethods().length > 0,
            configDefaultGroup: {
                name: 'methodGroup',
                component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group'
            },
            paymentGroupsList: [],
            defaultGroupTitle: $t('Select a new payment method')
        },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super().initDefaulGroup().initChildren();
            paymentMethods.subscribe(
                function (changes) {
                    checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
                    //remove renderer for "deleted" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'deleted') {
                            this.removeRenderer(change.value.method);
                        }
                    }, this);
                    //add renderer for "added" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'added') {
                            this.createRenderer(change.value);
                        }
                    }, this);
                }, this, 'arrayChange');

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().
                observe(['paymentGroupsList']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Creates default group
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initDefaulGroup: function () {
            layout([
                this.configDefaultGroup
            ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create renders for child payment methods.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            var self = this;

            _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @returns
         */
        createComponent: function (payment) {
            var rendererTemplate,
                rendererComponent,
                templateData;

            templateData = {
                parentName: this.name,
                name: payment.name
            };
            rendererTemplate = {
                parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
                name: '${ $.$data.name }',
                displayArea: payment.displayArea,
                component: payment.component
            };
            rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
            utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                item: payment.item,
                config: payment.config
            });

            return rendererComponent;
        },

        /**
         * Create renderer.
         *
         * @param {Object} paymentMethodData
         */
        createRenderer: function (paymentMethodData) {
            var isRendererForMethod = false,
                currentGroup;

            registry.get(this.configDefaultGroup.name, function (defaultGroup) {
                _.each(rendererList(), function (renderer) {

                    if (renderer.hasOwnProperty('typeComparatorCallback') &&
                        typeof renderer.typeComparatorCallback == 'function'
                    ) {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.typeComparatorCallback(renderer.type, paymentMethodData.method);
                    } else {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.type === paymentMethodData.method;
                    }

                    if (isRendererForMethod) {
                        currentGroup = renderer.group ? renderer.group : defaultGroup;

                        this.collectPaymentGroups(currentGroup);

                        layout([
                            this.createComponent(
                                {
                                    config: renderer.config,
                                    component: renderer.component,
                                    name: renderer.type,
                                    method: paymentMethodData.method,
                                    item: paymentMethodData,
                                    displayArea: currentGroup.displayArea
                                }
                            )]);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },

        /**
         * Collects unique groups of available payment methods
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         */
        collectPaymentGroups: function (group) {
            var groupsList = this.paymentGroupsList(),
                isGroupExists = _.some(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.alias === group.alias;
                });

            if (!isGroupExists) {
                groupsList.push(group);
                groupsList = _.sortBy(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.sortOrder;
                });
                this.paymentGroupsList(groupsList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment group title
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getGroupTitle: function (group) {
            var title = group().title;

            if (group().isDefault() && this.paymentGroupsList().length > 1) {
                title = this.defaultGroupTitle;
            }

            return title + ':';
        },

        /**
         * Checks if at least one payment method available
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        isPaymentMethodsAvailable: function () {
            return _.some(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                return this.getRegion(group.displayArea)().length;
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Remove view renderer.
         *
         * @param {String} paymentMethodCode
         */
        removeRenderer: function (paymentMethodCode) {
            var items;

            _.each(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                items = this.getRegion(group.displayArea);

                _.find(items(), function (value) {
                    if (value.item.method.indexOf(paymentMethodCode) === 0) {
                        value.disposeSubscriptions();
                        value.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }, this);
        }
    });
});
```

> CheckoutJazz/Radio/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 -->
 <h2>Techlets</h2>
 <div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
 class="items payment-methods">
<div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
     class="payment-group">
    <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
         translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
         class="step-title"
         data-role="title">
    </div>
    <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
</div>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
 class="no-payments-block"
 translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot add custom javascript code into html file....You can use your js code into specified uicomponent js files.

Comment: Also do not code into pub/static folders. it will change every content:deploy. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: so how can I make changes in the file `list.html` which is in **pub** folder @Ranganathan

Comment: like I want to know what will be the location of the `list.html` file that I mentioned above and also how can I add js code

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281539/cannot-read-property-click-of-undefined-in-magento-2-phtml-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Override in Theme

To override `list.html` file copy from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html`

to

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Yourtheme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template//payment-methods/list.html`

Run below command to see the changed

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Explore about Uicomponent method how Magento use to render html and js files - [Here](https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/ui-component-using-layout-xml-in-magento-2-664)

As mentioned above link list.html's correspondent js file is `staging/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js`

Magento uses Knockout.js, explore - [Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html)

Try to use js like how Magento used by default instead of hard code in core files.

> Override using Extension

**Step1:** `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="payments-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/payment/list</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step2:** `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js`. Add your custom html file path in template variable. And You can add your custom function here for list.html.

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function (_, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/payment-methods/list',
            visible: paymentMethods().length > 0,
            configDefaultGroup: {
                name: 'methodGroup',
                component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group'
            },
            paymentGroupsList: [],
            defaultGroupTitle: $t('Select a new payment method')
        },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super().initDefaulGroup().initChildren();
            paymentMethods.subscribe(
                function (changes) {
                    checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
                    //remove renderer for "deleted" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'deleted') {
                            this.removeRenderer(change.value.method);
                        }
                    }, this);
                    //add renderer for "added" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'added') {
                            this.createRenderer(change.value);
                        }
                    }, this);
                }, this, 'arrayChange');

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().
                observe(['paymentGroupsList']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Creates default group
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initDefaulGroup: function () {
            layout([
                this.configDefaultGroup
            ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create renders for child payment methods.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            var self = this;

            _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @returns
         */
        createComponent: function (payment) {
            var rendererTemplate,
                rendererComponent,
                templateData;

            templateData = {
                parentName: this.name,
                name: payment.name
            };
            rendererTemplate = {
                parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
                name: '${ $.$data.name }',
                displayArea: payment.displayArea,
                component: payment.component
            };
            rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
            utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                item: payment.item,
                config: payment.config
            });

            return rendererComponent;
        },

        /**
         * Create renderer.
         *
         * @param {Object} paymentMethodData
         */
        createRenderer: function (paymentMethodData) {
            var isRendererForMethod = false,
                currentGroup;

            registry.get(this.configDefaultGroup.name, function (defaultGroup) {
                _.each(rendererList(), function (renderer) {

                    if (renderer.hasOwnProperty('typeComparatorCallback') &&
                        typeof renderer.typeComparatorCallback == 'function'
                    ) {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.typeComparatorCallback(renderer.type, paymentMethodData.method);
                    } else {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.type === paymentMethodData.method;
                    }

                    if (isRendererForMethod) {
                        currentGroup = renderer.group ? renderer.group : defaultGroup;

                        this.collectPaymentGroups(currentGroup);

                        layout([
                            this.createComponent(
                                {
                                    config: renderer.config,
                                    component: renderer.component,
                                    name: renderer.type,
                                    method: paymentMethodData.method,
                                    item: paymentMethodData,
                                    displayArea: currentGroup.displayArea
                                }
                            )]);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },

        /**
         * Collects unique groups of available payment methods
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         */
        collectPaymentGroups: function (group) {
            var groupsList = this.paymentGroupsList(),
                isGroupExists = _.some(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.alias === group.alias;
                });

            if (!isGroupExists) {
                groupsList.push(group);
                groupsList = _.sortBy(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.sortOrder;
                });
                this.paymentGroupsList(groupsList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment group title
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getGroupTitle: function (group) {
            var title = group().title;

            if (group().isDefault() && this.paymentGroupsList().length > 1) {
                title = this.defaultGroupTitle;
            }

            return title + ':';
        },

        /**
         * Checks if at least one payment method available
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        isPaymentMethodsAvailable: function () {
            return _.some(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                return this.getRegion(group.displayArea)().length;
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Remove view renderer.
         *
         * @param {String} paymentMethodCode
         */
        removeRenderer: function (paymentMethodCode) {
            var items;

            _.each(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                items = this.getRegion(group.displayArea);

                _.find(items(), function (value) {
                    if (value.item.method.indexOf(paymentMethodCode) === 0) {
                        value.disposeSubscriptions();
                        value.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }, this);
        }
    });
});
```

**Step3:** Place your list.html here `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html`

Comment: can I change `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Yourtheme>/Magento_Checkout/web/template//payment-methods/list.html` to my extension `app/code/<Vendor>/<module>/Magento_Checkout/web/template//payment-methods/list.html`??

Comment: No, If you want to override via extension. You need to override `list.js` from `checkout_index_index.xml`. In `list.js` you can override template variable to your custom html file.

Comment: can you please update your answer that how can I set it in extension?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Sorry to disturb u Sir... but Sir I copied all of your code n create a new *module* and add some extra code to my `list.html` file but still it runs it own `list.html` file

Comment: Did you run upgrade and content deploy command?

Comment: Thank God u r still online... Yeah I checked it n my new module is enabled but `list.html` is still from the core file

Comment: let me tell you I just make `registration.php` and `module.xml` file else I copied everything from your code

Comment: Sorry I left...Will update the file path to make sure....May be some folder name is wrong in your module.

Comment: Thank u soo much Sir... can you also look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291037/how-to-write-knockout-js-code-magento-2 this question as well for me actually I'm really new in KnockoutJs

Comment: So, Is this issue closed?

Comment: No this one still remains... but I'm also trapped in the next one as well

Comment: Ok please check folder names are correct...will work on your next question and update with exact folder path.

Comment: Sir all the weekend I tried this but I cannot override this... can you please take a look again to your code?? or maybe I upload my code that u can check it?

Comment: I have created above code in my magento instance. It is working fine....Please upload your script, Will check and let you know

Comment: updated kindly check it

Comment: You have called template file in list.js as `template: 'Magento_Checkout/payment-methods/list',`....Use `template: 'CheckoutJazz_Radio/payment-methods/list',`

Comment: Once again Thank u soooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much Sir...

Comment: Np @AsadKhan, Happy coding

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again sir... but now the code works perfectly on Localhost but when I tried to run this extension on server then it do not works

Comment: You may miss some files to upload I think

Comment: Sir nothing is missed but still not working on server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99290/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-asad-khan).