# How to Write Knockout Js Code. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, knockout

I'm trying to Hide 3 Radio Buttons when Checkbox is unchecked when I checked it the all 3 buttons need to show in **Jquery** the code will be like

```
     show_hide_fun: function(){
             window.alert("Nadeem is running1");
             $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
             $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
             $("#custom_jazz_c").hide(); 
             $("#show_hide_jazz").click(function(){
                 if($("#show_hide_jazz").attr('checked'))
                 {window.alert("Nadeem is running2");
                     $("#custom_jazz_s").show();
                     $("#custom_jazz_m").show();
                     $("#custom_jazz_c").show();
                 }else{window.alert("Nadeem is running3");
                     $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
                     $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
                     $("#custom_jazz_c").hide();
                 }
             });      
     },
```

> list.html

```
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->

<h2>Pakistan</h2>
<div class="myJazz"><label for="show_hide_jazz">
     <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" id="show_hide_jazz" data-bind="event: { click: myFunction }"> JazzCash</label>
</div>
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
        <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
             translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
             class="step-title"
             data-role="title">
        </div>

        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

and the other Id's I mentioned in my Jquery code is coming from other `html` file

> JazzCashS/view/web/template/payment/form.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<div class="payment-method" id="custom_jazz_s" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KR3uhnuU3qo/W4fpRKRGM0I/AAAAAAAAAFc/cmogQ-czRIcsQTkDwR-ZanDT--s6SC3HQCL0BGAYYCw/h50/2018-08-30.png"
alt="JazzCash Shop" width="100px" height="50px"
/>

            <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <p>
           JazzCash Shop is an easy payment solution.<br /> Click "Place Order" and your JazzCash voucher number will be generated and displayed on your screen<br /> You can visit any JazzCash shop and pay against your token within 24 hours.<br /> To
            see the list of JazzCash shop locations, <a href="http://www.jazzcash.com.pk/agent-locator/">Click Here</a><br /> You are almost done!<br /> To change or edit your order, go back. No changes will be allowed once you click "Place Order".<br
            />
        </p><br><br>


        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- --><button class="action primary checkout" type="submit" data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JazzCashC/view/web/template/payment/form.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<div class="payment-method" id="custom_jazz_c" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}">

<!--       <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-t8IBL-2jMOY/W4T5YR_HaHI/AAAAAAAAAFA/x68pD0gVP-EnMXqDkuBg6v9UPlk6RkcoACL0BGAYYCw/h512/2018-08-28.png"
alt="Jazz Cash Credit Card" width="50px" height="50px" /> -->

  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-gqE4diqupEc/W4fpQTpyfnI/AAAAAAAAAFc/ccVFkANPyrgcVU1W-VAzMb-E6A7d7MDVgCL0BGAYYCw/h50/2018-08-30.png" alt="Jazz Cash Credit Card" width="100px" height="50px" />

            <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <p>
          Any local or international Visa/Mastercard Credit or Debit Card holder can pay online.<br /> Please make sure your card is activated for online shopping.<br /> You are almost done!<br /> To change or edit your order, go back. No changes will
            be allowed once you click "Place Order".<br />
        </p><br><br>



        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout" type="submit" data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> JazzCashM/view/web/template/payment/form.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<div class="payment-method" id="custom_jazz_m" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" />
        <label class="label" data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-oBKXNWhW9lY/W4fpR3i6tII/AAAAAAAAAFc/_KAo2ntBFTMuSfaNEhTqiD7gtoLO9tE4QCL0BGAYYCw/h50/2018-08-30.png" alt="JazzCash Mobile Account" width="100px" height="50px" />
            <span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <p>
            JazzCash Mobile Account can be registered on any Jazz or Warid number<br /> Biometric-verified Jazz and Warid customers can self-register their Mobile Account simply by dialing *786#.<br /> Enter the confirmation code within 30 seconds to
            make a successful payment!<br /> You are almost done!<br /> To change or edit your order, go back. No changes will be allowed once you click "Place Order".<br />
        </p><br><br>

        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <!-- --><button class="action primary checkout" type="submit" data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')}">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I add this code in my `list.js` file then it gives me many **errors** because this is a **Jquery** code how can I write the above code in **knockoutjs** like when `#show_hide_jazz` is unclicked then `#custom_jazz_s`, `#custom_jazz_m` and `#custom_jazz_c` needs to be hidden n when I clicked on `#show_hide_jazz` then it need to be shown...
[image]

Comment: Please update your html..

Comment: updated kindly check it

Comment: I think you updated by mistake...please review once again

Comment: #show_hide_jazz is radio button or checkbox?

Comment: kindly check the updated question. #show_hide_jazz is the Radio button which is mentioned in `list.html`

Comment: But i can see `JazzCashM/view/web/template/payment/form.html` in two places in your question.

Comment: from where?? if you can see kindly ignore it... it maybe my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folder path:

[image: Folder Path]

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js

Added customChange function.

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list',
    'uiLayout',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'mage/translate',
    'uiRegistry'
], function ($, _, ko, utils, Component, paymentMethods, rendererList, layout, checkoutDataResolver, $t, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/payment-methods/list',
            visible: paymentMethods().length > 0,
            configDefaultGroup: {
                name: 'methodGroup',
                component: 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group'
            },
            paymentGroupsList: [],
            defaultGroupTitle: $t('Select a new payment method')
        },

        /**
         * Initialize view.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super().initDefaulGroup().initChildren();
            paymentMethods.subscribe(
                function (changes) {
                    checkoutDataResolver.resolvePaymentMethod();
                    //remove renderer for "deleted" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'deleted') {
                            this.removeRenderer(change.value.method);
                        }
                    }, this);
                    //add renderer for "added" payment methods
                    _.each(changes, function (change) {
                        if (change.status === 'added') {
                            this.createRenderer(change.value);
                        }
                    }, this);
                }, this, 'arrayChange');

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().
                observe(['paymentGroupsList']);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Creates default group
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initDefaulGroup: function () {
            layout([
                this.configDefaultGroup
            ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Create renders for child payment methods.
         *
         * @returns {Component} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            var self = this;

            _.each(paymentMethods(), function (paymentMethodData) {
                self.createRenderer(paymentMethodData);
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @returns
         */
        createComponent: function (payment) {
            var rendererTemplate,
                rendererComponent,
                templateData;

            templateData = {
                parentName: this.name,
                name: payment.name
            };
            rendererTemplate = {
                parent: '${ $.$data.parentName }',
                name: '${ $.$data.name }',
                displayArea: payment.displayArea,
                component: payment.component
            };
            rendererComponent = utils.template(rendererTemplate, templateData);
            utils.extend(rendererComponent, {
                item: payment.item,
                config: payment.config
            });

            return rendererComponent;
        },

        /**
         * Create renderer.
         *
         * @param {Object} paymentMethodData
         */
        createRenderer: function (paymentMethodData) {
            var isRendererForMethod = false,
                currentGroup;

            registry.get(this.configDefaultGroup.name, function (defaultGroup) {
                _.each(rendererList(), function (renderer) {

                    if (renderer.hasOwnProperty('typeComparatorCallback') &&
                        typeof renderer.typeComparatorCallback == 'function'
                    ) {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.typeComparatorCallback(renderer.type, paymentMethodData.method);
                    } else {
                        isRendererForMethod = renderer.type === paymentMethodData.method;
                    }

                    if (isRendererForMethod) {
                        currentGroup = renderer.group ? renderer.group : defaultGroup;

                        this.collectPaymentGroups(currentGroup);

                        layout([
                            this.createComponent(
                                {
                                    config: renderer.config,
                                    component: renderer.component,
                                    name: renderer.type,
                                    method: paymentMethodData.method,
                                    item: paymentMethodData,
                                    displayArea: currentGroup.displayArea
                                }
                            )]);
                    }
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
        },

        /**
         * Collects unique groups of available payment methods
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         */
        collectPaymentGroups: function (group) {
            var groupsList = this.paymentGroupsList(),
                isGroupExists = _.some(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.alias === group.alias;
                });

            if (!isGroupExists) {
                groupsList.push(group);
                groupsList = _.sortBy(groupsList, function (existsGroup) {
                    return existsGroup.sortOrder;
                });
                this.paymentGroupsList(groupsList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Returns payment group title
         *
         * @param {Object} group
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getGroupTitle: function (group) {
            var title = group().title;

            if (group().isDefault() && this.paymentGroupsList().length > 1) {
                title = this.defaultGroupTitle;
            }

            return title + ':';
        },

        /**
         * Checks if at least one payment method available
         *
         * @returns {String}
         */
        isPaymentMethodsAvailable: function () {
            return _.some(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                return this.getRegion(group.displayArea)().length;
            }, this);
        },

        /**
         * Remove view renderer.
         *
         * @param {String} paymentMethodCode
         */
        removeRenderer: function (paymentMethodCode) {
            var items;

            _.each(this.paymentGroupsList(), function (group) {
                items = this.getRegion(group.displayArea);

                _.find(items(), function (value) {
                    if (value.item.method.indexOf(paymentMethodCode) === 0) {
                        value.disposeSubscriptions();
                        value.destroy();
                    }
                });
            }, this);
        },

        customChange: function () {
            if( $("#show_hide_jazz").attr('checked') ) {
                $("#custom_jazz_s").show();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").show();
                $("#custom_jazz_c").show();
            } else {
                $("#custom_jazz_s").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_m").hide();
                $("#custom_jazz_c").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html

Added customChange as change event

```
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->

<h2>Pakistan</h2>
<div class="myJazz"><label for="show_hide_jazz">
     <input type="radio" name="payment[method]" id="show_hide_jazz" data-bind="event: { change: customChange }"> JazzCash</label>
</div>
<div if="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="items payment-methods">
    <div repeat="foreach: paymentGroupsList, item: '$group'"
         class="payment-group">
        <div if="getRegion($group().displayArea)().length"
             translate="getGroupTitle($group)"
             class="step-title"
             data-role="title">
        </div>

        <each args="data: getRegion($group().displayArea), as: 'method'" render=""/>
    <h2>Testing</h2>
</div>
<div ifnot="isPaymentMethodsAvailable()"
     class="no-payments-block"
     translate="'No Payment Methods'">
</div>
```

Run below comment

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Sir it gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: updated...pls check

Comment: Sir now the ids of external `html` files is not accepted. Like it returns me nothing

Comment: `#custom_jazz_s` these Ids

Comment: not accepted means?......I can't get you

Comment: like as you know that the values `#custom_jazz_s` ,`#custom_jazz_m` and `#custom_jazz_c` are not coming from the same `html` so when I used these radio buttons id to hide or show then the id is not accepted by list.js file they are not changing the value of these radio buttons

Comment: You asked to hide those radio buttons when `show_hide_jazz` checked, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly.... but when i click on the button then it do not accept the ids of other radio buttons

Comment: By default you need to hide those radio buttons....write display none in inline for #custom_jazz_s ,#custom_jazz_m and #custom_jazz_c

Comment: I tried that as well... but it is not accepting these Ids...

Comment: `$("#custom_jazz_s").show(); <br>
                $("#custom_jazz_m").show(); <br>
                $("#custom_jazz_c").show()` <br> I mean these Ids are not accepted

Comment: Initially to hide radio button, did you tried with js?...Like `$("#custom_jazz_s").hide();`

Comment: Yeah when it was not working then I tried this

Comment: No you have to hide like `<div class="payment-method" id="custom_jazz_m" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}" style="display: none">` from form.html

Comment: I tried this as well but I think it is not accepting the id in js file

Comment: No, Id will accept any js file from single page when you use jquery

Comment: If you edit the js or html files you need to re run the mention commands....Did you execute those?

Comment: Yeah I used the commands every single time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99159/discussion-between-ranganathan-and-asad-khan).